# Functions and classes of PHP extentions in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, yaf, phalcon

Are functions of an extension fetch-able for an IDE like PHPStorm when they are given path to php.ini file of extension folder path? I saw that EasyPHP list functions of an extension beside it for those extension that are delivered with it, but it do not display any function for Yaf and Phalcon that is manually installed.

Comment: "Are functions of an extension fetch-able..." -- **NO** -- IDE will know nothing about it unless stub files provided by somebody (be it PhpStorm itself, creator/developer of such PHP extension or some 3rd party person/company). This applies to any PHP IDE/Editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **Phalcon** -- get yourself **Phalcon Developer Tools** ( http://phalconphp.com/download ) -- it contains stub files that can be used by IDE for code completion: https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/tree/master/ide/phpstorm

For **Yaf** -- similar approach (stub file for usage inside IDE): https://github.com/suin/phpstorm-yaf-doc

Answer (score 1):

As this frameworks are php extensions, just make sure, you have configured you php include path in IDE right.

config -> PHP -> and add there something like **/usr/share/php** *(your location)*

Answer (score 1):

I use the stubs provided on packagist and install them with composer. https://packagist.org/packages/sneakybobito/phalcon-stubs

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "sneakybobito/phalcon-stubs": "1.2.3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For compiled extensions you will need a stub file which contains the name of the functions.  Since recent versions of PHP include reflection capabilities for extensions[you can get the extension defined classes and functions and then reflect them to get their parameters] they should be possible to generate them.

I'm giving https://github.com/schmittjoh/php-stubs a try but the PHP svn server is down at the moment so it won't run...  Will try to check back here later and update on if it works.